# Execute command doesn't work (Bedrock)

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm on Minecraft bedrock and my execute command isn't working. I didn't turn on experiments or anything like that, so why isn't it working? This is my execute command.

`/execute @e[name="iron bars"] ~~~ effect @p[r=20] health_boost 999999 0 true`

Comment: your tildes (~) seem to be in the wrong place. each of them need to be spaced out, e.g. "~ ~ ~" vs "~~~".

Comment: @EarthToAccess I did that, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Mojang changed Bedrock's execute command to be more like Java's execute command.
Try changing your command to `/execute as @e[name="iron bars"] at @s run effect @p[r=20] health_boost 999999 0 true`

Comment: Ty so much! I really needed this for my realm!